# The project cannot be built until its prerequisite com.meta.clientinfo.view is built.cleaning and building all projects is recommended

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I have this error at problems tab.

```
    The project cannot be built until its prerequisite 

com.meta.clientinfo.view is built.Cleaning and building all projects is 

recommended.
```

I did cleaning and building over and over again, but the error still remains.Due to this problem, I guess, I have red mark on some of my packages.

What's the reason of this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: i would try closing all the projects in eclipse except the one you want to build and then try building.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I have only one project, that has many packages inside, at package explorer.

Comment: okay well where is com.meta.clientinfo.view?

Comment: com.meta.clientinfo.view is one of the packages under the project.

Comment: So I'm assuming you have placed this jar under the project to use it? Where are you using it? Is it needed?